# codeigniter get_where and order_by

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code

This is my controller

```
function menu()
{ 
  $data['query'] = $this->get_where_custom('key', 'value');
  $data['view_file'] = 'menu';
  $this->load->view($data);
}

function get_where_custom($col, $value) 
{
  $this->load->model('mdl_menu');
  $query = $this->mdl_menu->get_where_custom($col, $value);
  return $query;
}
```

This is my model

```
function get_where_custom($col, $value) {
  $table = $this->get_table();
  $this->db->where($col, $value);
  $query=$this->db->get($table);
  return $query;
}
```

I am showing the value in table I have a column name `date_posted` in database. I want the table to be order by `date_posted`. How may I approach this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can add **"get_where_custom"** inside function **$this->db->order_by($col);** $col as date_posted assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model use `$this->db->order_by('column_name');` like below:

```
function get_where_custom($col, $value) {
  $table = $this->get_table();
  $this->db->order_by('date_posted');
  $query = $this->db->get_where($table,array($col=>$value));
  return $query;
}
```